# Stuck at message passing background.html >> contentscript.js (chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, message-passing

I know it's been here like thousand times, but I'm stuck now. I've read plenty of answers and studied the code.google.com but didn't succeed. I am trying to send a request in a chrome extension from `background.html` to `contentscript.js`. I managed to get it work the other way though.

Code inside `background.html`:

```
  chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
      console.log(response.farewell);
     });
  });
```

Code inside `contentscript.js`:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.greeting == "hello")
      sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
    else
      sendResponse({farewell: "nope"});
});
```

The `manifest.json` should be fine as the communication is working backwards and anything else works properly. Thank you!

Comment: Is the message received in contentscript ?

Comment: No, even if I add `alert("Hey");` inside the `function(request, sender, sendResponse){}` nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is good, there must be something wrong with your trigger. I created a simple extension using your code and it worked. Add these two bits to your background and contentscript. Then rmb on any page and choose 'Send Message.' You should receive an alert.

Background.html

```
var menuid = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title":"Send Message", "onclick": SendMessage, "documentUrlPatterns":["http://*/*"]});

function SendMessage() {        
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
            chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
                console.log(response.farewell);
             });
    });
}
```

contentscript

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.greeting == "hello") {
            alert('hello');
      sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
        }
    else
        {
            alert('goodbye');
      sendResponse({farewell: "nope"});
        }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. But still don't know why the other way doesn't. I used the action browser onclicked event which works fine as well.